# How to create a dynamic component in angular 6 when prod mode is on

Tags: angular, angular6

I had a requirement where i was creating a dynamic componnent using angular5.
I had writtena directive which generated a component. It worked fine in dev/prod mode both. But on upgrading the app to angular6 it doesnt work as in prod mode when AOT is "ON", the compiler class is unavailable. how can i re-design my soln so as it works in angular6 ?

```
export class HtmlOutletDirective implements OnChanges {
@Input() html: string;
constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler, 
private translate: TranslateService) {
}

ngOnChanges() {
const html = this.html;
if (!html) { return; }

@Component({
  selector: 'ccw-dynamic-component',
  template: `
    <div [innerHtml]="innerHtmlTemplate">
    </div>
    `
})

class DynamicHtmlComponent {
  private innerHtmlTemplate: any = '';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.httpClient.get(html, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe((htmlContent) => {
      this.innerHtmlTemplate = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlContent.toString());
    });
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [DynamicHtmlComponent]
})

class DynamicHtmlModule { }

this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
  .then(factory => {
    const compFactory = factory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === DynamicHtmlComponent);
    const compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory, 0);
  });
 }
```

I call my directive like this in my component:

```
   <mat-accordion [multi]="true">
        <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor='let releaseNote of releaseNotes'>
            <mat-panel-description>
                <dcHtmlOutlet [html]="releaseNote.html"></dcHtmlOutlet>
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
```

Below is the error i get:

```
 Runtime compiler is not loaded Error stack trace: Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded at Le (main.00612d315fe86075b5fb.js:1) at t.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync
```

Comment: How do you load your dynamic component? Can you share detail? And detail of error message? There are several ways to load dynamic component such as you can compile on the fly

Comment: @sugarme added how i am loading component and error

Comment: My understand from the error message that Angular needs compiler at runtime and it is not available, meaning your components are compiled at browser (runtime) and for some reason it is not as guided by AOT. A good try should be creating a custom JIT compiler and pack it with your dynamic component instead of using default one.

Comment: JIT compiler something like this: ```import { JitCompilerFactory } from '@angular/compiler';

export function createJitCompiler() {
  return new JitCompilerFactory([{
    useDebug: false,
    useJit: true
  }]).createCompiler();
}

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: Compiler, useFactory: createJitCompiler}],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
}```

Comment: let me know how you go with that. I will update with different dynamic loading component strategy later on (1. in the same module with host view, 2. Different module (lazy load module), 3. On the fly)

Comment: Can you share your complete `HtmlOutletDirective`? When do you compile your `DynamicHtmlComponent` and its module? at `ngOnChanges()` or at `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hooks?

Comment: import { JitCompilerFactory } from '@angular/compiler' doesnt work as this api isn't public anymore

Comment: Yes. It has been moved to `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`. Check out this link https://angular.io/api/platform-browser-dynamic/JitCompilerFactory

Comment: If you can share your whole `HtmlOutletDirective` I might have a try as I don't know where and when you compile your dynamic component.

Comment: @pankaj any solution to the issue ? I am facing same issue